# No response back on FaceBook sharing

Tags: jquery, facebook, fbml, fbconnect

I want to catch the response when a share is made on Facebook and on the response an alert will occur.

I made the following script

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId:'<?php echo $this->config->item('appID'); ?>', cookie:true,
            status:true, xfbml:true,oauth : true
        });
     };

     (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {
             return;
         }
         js = d.createElement('script');
         js.id = id;
         js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
     }(document));

     function get_fb_share() {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'feed',
            name: 'IGUTS Share',
            link: "<?php echo base_url();?>",
            picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
            caption: 'Reference Documentation',
            description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.',
            message: 'Facebook Dialogs are easy!'
        }, function(response) {
            if (response && response.post_id) {
                alert('Post was published.');
            } else {
                alert('Post was not published.');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I put the above code on header.

Then I am calling the `get_fb_share()` by the following manner:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo base_url();?>" 
                                                     data-width="50" data-type="button_count"
                                                     onclick="get_fb_share();"></div>
```

Now I don't know what I made wrong; I can share the link, but I can't get any FB response.

Can anybody tell me why?

### Edit

What I found out is that when I am using this div for the sharing i.e.

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo base_url();?>" 
                                                         data-width="50" data-type="button_count"
                                                         onclick="get_fb_share();"></div>
```

I am not getting any response.

But if I use a normal button like this, i.e.

```
<input type="button" onclick="get_fb_share();" value="share"/>
```

Then I am getting the response. But this is not perfect. I am using the Facebook

```
<div class="fb-share-button">
```

Because it shows the no. of shares as well. That's why I need the get_fb_share() function be called by the Facebook sharing div and not just by any button.

Answer (score 0):

**I´ve answered this in a newer thread, but i will just copy my answer here:**

The feed dialog is deprecated afaik, you should use the [share dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) instead. It´s a lot easier to handle:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: your-url
}, function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

This is what i get in the console when i cancel the share:

> Object {error_code: 4201, error_message: "User canceled the Dialog flow"}

...and this is what i get when i share:

> []

Yes, that´s an empty array, and it will hit the "Post not published" alert. The post id will only be available if you authorize the user with `publish_actions`, as you can read in the docs.

This worked for me:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: your-url
}, function (response) {
    if (response.error_code) {
        console.log(response);
    } else {
        console.log('published');
    }
});
```

BUT: You should not use those callbacks imho, incentivizing shares is not allowed and the user should be able to share more often if he wants to.