# No Response Back On FaceBook Sharing?

Tags: jquery, facebook, fbml, fbconnect

i want to catch the response when a share is made on facebook and on the response an alert will occur.
 i made the following script
**Note:** This question already asked but not answered yet. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23715680/no-response-back-on-facebook-sharing)

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
                         {
                                FB.init({
                                appId:'<?php echo $this->config->item('appID'); ?>', cookie:true,
                                status:true, xfbml:true,oauth : true
                                        });
                         };
                        (function(d){
                                var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                                if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                                js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
                                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                                ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
                                }(document));

function get_fb_share()
{
    FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'feed',
     name: 'IGUTS Share',
     link: "<?php echo base_url();?>",
     picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
     caption: 'Reference Documentation',
     description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.',
     message: 'Facebook Dialogs are easy!'
   },
   function(response) {
     if (response && response.post_id) {
       alert('Post was published.');
     } else {
       alert('Post was not published.');
     }
   }
 );
}
</script>
```

i put the above code on header

then i am calling the get_fb_share() by the following manner

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo base_url();?>" 
                                                 data-width="50" data-type="button_count"
                                                 onclick="get_fb_share();"></div>
```

Now i dont know what I made wrong, i can share the link, but I can't get any FB response.

Can anybody tell me why??

```
EDIT
```

What i found out is that when I am using this div for the sharing i.e.

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo base_url();?>" 
                                                     data-width="50" data-type="button_count"
                                                     onclick="get_fb_share();"></div>
```

I am not getting any response.

But if I use a normal button like this, i.e.

```
<input type="button" onclick="get_fb_share();" value="share"/>
```

Then I am getting the response. But this is not perfect. I am using the facebook

```
<div class="fb-share-button">
```

cause it shows the no. of shares as well. Thats why i need the get_fb_share() function be called by the facebook sharing div and not just by any button.

Please help me find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The feed dialog is deprecated afaik, you should use the [share dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) instead. It´s a lot easier to handle and just takes the Open Graph tags from the URL:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: your-url
}, function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

This is what i get in the console when i cancel the share:

> Object {error_code: 4201, error_message: "User canceled the Dialog flow"}

...and this is what i get when i share:

> []

Yes, that´s an empty array, and it will hit the "Post not published" alert. The post id will only be available if you authorize the user with `publish_actions`, as you can read in the docs.

This worked for me:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: your-url
}, function (response) {
    if (response.error_code) {
        console.log(response);
    } else {
        console.log('published');
    }
});
```

BUT: You should not use those callbacks imho, incentivizing shares is not allowed and the user should be able to share more often if he wants to.